# Do I need a tenancy agreement in my name for T2 Dependant visa [UK]?

Tags: united-kingdom, eu-spouses, uk-citizens, dependent-visa, children

Im applying for my daughter to come join me in March 2019. She was born in UK but had to travel back for a few months as her mother needed to be back home for some family matters (The mother has a T2 Dependant visa until May 2019).

Since they have left, I have moved into shared accommodation where I pay for only 1 room. I dont have any tenancy agreement in my name as I saw no reason to pay for a full house when I needed only 1 room for myself.

Now that I am filling her application, I am asked for a UK address where she will be staying.

What address should I give? Should I give my current UK address? But I dont have a tenancy agreement for this.

What are my options? I cant even go rent a house from now, just for the visa, that will be very expensive and wasteful 4 months rent pay.

I am sure many people would have faced a similar problem to mine. Please advise what to do.

Thank you

Comment: Are you planning to live with your daughter in only one room when she arrives?

Comment: My daughter will be traveling with her mother. I intend to get a 2 bedroom flat before they arrive, but that will be in March 2019. Sorry I should have clarified this in my question

Comment: Is there anything preventing you from finding a new flat and agreeing the tenancy with effect from March?

Comment: Its too far ahead, no landlord is willing to hold a property for that long unless I start paying for it. The properties the landlord does have, he is not sure if they will be vacated by March

Comment: What address have you registered with eg your bank/credit card provider, HMRC, DVLA, your employer?

Comment: @StuckInPhD A landlord with a tenant moving out in February may well be willing to sign a lease starting in March.  Those may be rare, but they can exist.